# how to destroy session value in saving web page

Tags: javascript, php, sql, session

I want to destroy session when my webpage is save(Ctrl+s) in local system.

```
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['id']))
    {
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];
    print_r($admin_id);
    }
  else
    {
    echo 'not avil';
    }
}
```

when i am saving my web page  i am getting id

so, i do not want to print id, i want *"not avil"* when my web page and open form on local system.
  can any one have solution for this  in PHP or java script?

Comment: unable to understand.

Comment: why you have to do this? If any one saving locally then whats the problem with ession?

Comment: Why do you even want them not to save the page? They can still go to the developer console, view the page source or even use a website copier like HTTrack.

Comment: i want destroy session values when web page is save in local system and open from local system

Comment: What is the point of that because right now, what you are saying makes no sense. What does the session have to do with saving the page?

Comment: You said "when I am saving my web page I am getting id" No, that is not correct. You will only have the HTML content and not the PHP code. Therefore, the session id won't appear.

Answer (score 0):

Add an event listener that listens for the SHIFT and S key when pressed together, delete your data when it calls a function.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp